# How to publish Typescript type definitions in node_module with nested paths?

Tags: typescript

I have a node package thats written in Flow. I now need to publish Typescript definitions for it without removing the Flow types. The problem is, the way objects are usually imported are as follows:

```
import { myPackageFunction } from 'myPackage/lib/packageFunctions';
```

I'm struggling to align my type definitions and my actual code. How do I export my definition correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

- Set `declaration` to `true` in your tsconfig.json. Now when you compile the .ts files you should get a `.d.ts` file. Set `outDir` to `lib`.
- Add `types` to your package.json pointing to the out dir `"types" : "lib"`

Now when you publish `import { myPackageFunction } from 'myPackage/lib/packageFunctions';` will just work.